# How to show Dart class descriptions Vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

In VS code it os possible to see little notes about functions or classes in packages.

You can hover over code a see a popup as the image below
[image: example of class description]

When I look at the class itself this just appears to be comments above the class definition.

[image: example of comments above classs definition. They match the class description above]

Comments that I place above my classes do not appear in a similar way. What do I need to do in order to have them show here?

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed after posting. The comments have three slashes `///`

so the comments show if you put three slashes